# gcloud CLI application logs to bucket

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, log4j, google-cloud-dataproc

There are Scala application Spark jobs that run daily in GCP. I am trying to set up a notification to be sent when run is compeleted. So, one way I thought of doing that was to get the logs and `grep` for a specific completion message from it (not sure if there's a better way). But I figured out the logs are just being shown in the console, inside the job details page and not being saved on a file.

Is there a way to route these logs to a file in a bucket so that I can search in it? Do I have to specify where to show these logs in the log4j properties file, like give a bucket location to
`log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`

I tried to submit a job with this but it's giving me this error:  `grep:**-2022-07-08.log: No such file or directory`

```
...

gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --project $PROJECT --cluster=$CLUSTER --region=$REGION --class=***.spark.offer.Main \
    --jars=gs://**.jar\
    --properties=driver-memory=10G,spark.ui.filters="",spark.memory.fraction=0.6,spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=5368709120,spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1,spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dcq.config.name=gcp.conf",spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-executor.properties -Dcq.config.name=gcp.conf" \
    --gcp.conf > gs://***-$date.log  2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Dataproc job driver logs are saved in GCS at the Dataproc-generated `driverOutputResourceUri` of the job. See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output#job_driver_output) for more details.

But IMHO, a better way to determine if a job has finished is through `gcloud dataproc jobs describe <job-id>` [1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/describe), or the jobs.get REST API [2](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/get).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The job id is auto-generated. Is there a way to specify it when doing ```job submit```?

Comment: I don't see a way to specify job ID, but you might be able to use `gcloud dataproc jobs list [--cluster=CLUSTER] ` to list jobs of a cluster.

Comment: So, I tried ```gcloud dataproc jobs describe``` for a currently running job but it said the job isn't found. It shows it's running in the console and also when doing```jobs list``` Does it work only for a completed ones?

Comment: Are you using job ID or UUID? there is a difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, I am using the job id, double checked that before running